# Self used before self.init called in custom UIGestureRecognizer class

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

What would be the proper way to subclass UITapGestureRecognizer and initialize a variable passed to my convenience constructor before I call the constructor that needs to get passed a reference to itself for later use?

Here is my code that doesn't compile yet:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

typealias ActionBlock = (BlockTapGestureRecognizer) -> Void

class BlockTapGestureRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer {

    private var handler: ActionBlock?

    convenience init?(handler block: @escaping ActionBlock) {
        self.init(target:self, action:#selector(self.performAction(_:)))
        self.handler = block
    }

    func performAction(_ recognizer: BlockTapGestureRecognizer) {
        if let block = self.handler {
            block(self)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `self` and `self.performAction(_:)` are both being referenced before the call to `self.init` can be made. This violates the order of initialization requirements in Swift.

One solution would be to delay the setting of the target and action.

```
convenience init?(handler block: @escaping ActionBlock) {
    super.init()
    addTarget(self, action:#selector(performAction))
    self.handler = block
}
```

Note that if your `BlockTapGestureRecognizer` doesn't actually have any other `init` method that it explicitly declares, then this `init` method can't be a `convenience` and it shouldn't be optional because it can't fail:

```
init(handler block: @escaping ActionBlock) {
    super.init()
    addTarget(self, action:#selector(performAction))
    self.handler = block
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus The joy of copy and paste :) Thanks